# inserting a cut out image from a computer into html code

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a form that has a button to select an image. I need to select an image and after reloading the page the image appears in the form. How can I do it? I'm writing on Python, Flask. Here is the code of the page:

```
@app.route('/load_photo', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def load_photo():
    global FILE

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return f'''<!doctype html>
            <html lang="en">
              <head>
                <title>Пример формы</title>
              </head>
                <body>
                  <h1 class="mytext">Анкета претендента</h1>
                  <h2 class="mytext">на участие в миссии</h2>
                  <form class="login_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {'<img src=' +  FILE.filename + '>' if FILE else ''}
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="photo">Приложите фотографию</label>
                      <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="photo" name="file">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Отправить</button>
                  </form>
                </body>
            <html>
        '''
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        #i dont know what can I do here
        return 'ok'
```

I tried to insert an `img` tag if there is something in `request.files['file']`, but actually I think I have a problem getting the absolute path to a file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to insert an image i selected. Button opens dialog window and there i select an image. This image must be in a form. How to do it?